# Using UE5.0's OpenCV module to load the DNN pre-trained model,crash

Tags: opencv, dotnetnuke, unreal-engine5, pre-trained-model

## Using UE5.0's OpenCV module to load the DNN pre-trained model, the program crashes

> When I included OpenCV in the plugin, the engineering code compiled successfully, but when I ran it with the Actor I created and then loaded the pretrained model using cv::d nn::readNetFromCaffe, it crashed；the model is "res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000_fp16.caffemodel",Prototex is "deploy.prototxt"。 run it on windows platform.

```
    FString PluginConfigDir = FPaths::ProjectPluginsDir() + "HiKVision/Config/";
    TSharedPtr<FJsonObject> Obj = GetJsonObjectFromFile(PluginConfigDir, FString("WaterCurtainDoor.json"));
    day_confidence = (float)Obj->GetNumberField("dayConfidence");
    night_confidence = (float)Obj->GetNumberField("nightConfidence");
    AlphaValue = (float)Obj->GetNumberField("alphaValue");
    BrightlessValue = (float)Obj->GetNumberField("BrightlessValue");
    Yolo3Confidence = (float)Obj->GetNumberField("Yolo3Confidence");
    OpenFace = Obj->GetBoolField("Openfacerecognition");
    OpenBody = Obj->GetBoolField("OpenBodyrecognition");
    bUseTCP = Obj->GetBoolField("UseTCP");
    /**DNN Face Recognation*/
    FString DnnModels = PluginConfigDir + TEXT("res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000_fp16.caffemodel");
    FString DNNBinary = PluginConfigDir + TEXT("deploy.prototxt");
    std::string cstrModels =TCHAR_TO_UTF8(*DnnModels);
    std::string cstrBinary = TCHAR_TO_UTF8(*DNNBinary);
    net = cv::dnn::readNetFromCaffe(cstrBinary, cstrModels);
```

[image: 1]

1. Check the file path
2. Recompile the OpenCV 4.5.5 library
3. Use other advanced versions of the library 4.7.0
4. I was OK to use OpenCV version 4.3.0, but it was in unreal engine version 4.27, not version 5.0
5. Maybe there is something wrong with the new OpenCV call